# My host doesn't support secure file transfers. I don't have root access. Do I have any options at all?

Tags: apache-2.2, file-transfer, security, ftps

I like this host a lot, and the lack of secure file transfer is the only thing stopping me from committing to them for a new e-commerce site. I've seen a few recommendations for WebDav, but that would still involve at least one change on the host, namely enabling the mod_dav Apache module.  I tried looking for open source PHP FTPS servers but had no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what kinds of access you do have, as that is likely to affect possible solutions.

Comment: It's a shared web hosting environment. Dedicated IP, true SSL.  I currently use regular FTP to do file transfers. No shell/command line access.  No root access.  I can't install executables on the server. I can't control which Apache modules are enabled.  I do have the ability to modify PHP settings via custom PHP.INI files. I have access to folders outside/above the public web root, so I can properly password-protect arbitrary folders in the public web folders. That's all I can think of.

Comment: More details: typical uploads would be web software like osCommerce, web site files (HTML/CSS/images) and data in the form of SQL.  Downloads would be database backups in the form of SQL.  Communication with the e-commerce software is already all encrypted via HTTPS.

Comment: ah, Duck Amuck! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Amuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try simple CGI/PHP form uploads via HTTPS.

Or, if the host machine has the software, you could try using PHP to [decrypt](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-encrypt/) files that you upload encrypted.  Note, you may not have access to GPG/PGP, but most Unix platforms have "crypt" (not the strongest crypto, mind you, but in a pinch...) and most likely will have openssl which can be used to encrypt/decrypt.

Worst case (no access to local executables or a non-Unix platform) I'm sure there is ready-made PHP code for encrypting and decrypting local files.  On Stack Overflow, the [mcrypt module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505529/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-text-from-file-with-php) was suggested.  Sure, it's a lot of extra work, but it's an option.

Where there's a will (or a whip), there's a way.

Comment: Interesting. So I could write or find some PHP code (form/CGI) to do the uploads and downloads from within an HTTPS connection. If I was moving a lot of files that would be a pain, but if I encrypted the files into a single archive file I could then decrypt/expand it on the other end. A bit clunky but if I automated the process to some extent it shouldn't be too awkward.  Of course, I was hoping for something magic that involves zero work (grin) but this is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If you are already doing it over a HTTPS connection, would that not already be secure?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for uploading files to the server? Do they provide SSH? If they do, you could transfer things over SFTP.

Comment: Yes, for uploading web software, web site files and SQL data and for downloading SQL data.  No SSH, unfortunately.  That would be sweet.